# Why can't able to use if/else in AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-asynctask

Why I can't able to use if/else block in **AsyncTast**.

When I try using if/else its throwing me "**Syntax Error**".

This is my code junk.

```
    package com.xyz.asd;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public class MapActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
            locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // taking location by GPS / network 
            if(location!=null)
            {
    // move camear to latlong by locationManager 
    new HttpGetTask().execute();
            }
            else
            {
                // pass hard coded lat long to move camera
                new HttpGetTask().execute();
            }

            if (location != null) {
    //Display some toast
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
    // bla bla
        }
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
    // bla bla
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // bla bla
        }
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // bla bla             
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //bla 
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //bla
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }


        private class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog
            }
            Double lat = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)
                    .getLatitude();
            Double lng = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)
                    .getLongitude();

**//*************************PROBLEM IN IF ELSE***********************************
            if(lat != null && lng!= null)
            {String URL = "http://xyz.in/api/stores/around_me.json?app_id=test&lat="
                    + lat + "&lng=" + lng; }
            else
            {
            String URL = "http://xyz.in/api/stores/around_me.json?       
                               app_id=test&lat=12.58&lng=77.38";
            }
//********************************************************************************

            AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);

                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                try {
                    return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
                } catch (ClientProtocolException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                try {

    //JSON parsing 
                    }
                });
                if (null != mClient)
                    mClient.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anybody suggest me what/why it is showing this behavior?
Am I wrong?  How can I correct my condition to pass valid URL to my http get request?

Comment: Clear your basics! Check the syntax of if and else

Comment: You need to read about basics of Java. Before doing an application dev.

Comment: Change `if(lat&&lng!= null)` to `if(lat != null && lng!= null)
`

Comment: @Jens thanks for your suggestion i was nut, But still after changing it into "if(lat != null && lng!= null)" it is giving me "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" error.

you know what it actually means.?

Comment: @ByzantineFailure,@Pankaj Kumar Thanks, i was totally nut, but after changing my condition as other suggested still i am getting "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" error. what it mean.?

Comment: Edit your question, post updated code.

Comment: Yor are outside of any methode in your class!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The if is not in any method. It's just lose at the class level. Put it inside the do in background or better yet its own method:

```
private String getUrl(Double lat, Double long) {
   if(lat != null && lng!= null) {
      String URL = "http://xyz.in/api/stores/around_me.json?app_id=test&lat="
                + lat + "&lng=" + lng;
      return URL;
   }
   else {
      String URL = "http://xyz.in/api/stores/around_me.json?       
                           app_id=test&lat=12.58&lng=77.38";
      return URL;
   }
}
```

As the other answers point out the if condition also has a problem. That should become clearer once it's in a valid place.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion as other suggested i modified my condition to "if(lat != null && lng!= null)" but it is still giving 
"Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)" Can you please elaborate.?

Comment: Have added a method example.

Answer (score 1):

First correct this

```
if(lat&&lng!= null)
```

Your **if** condition should be like

```
if(lat!= null && lng!= null)
```

Comment: Really?? His code is outside of any block.

Comment: this code is not even in a code block

Comment: @Simple Plan Thanks for your suggestion but still i am getting same error "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"

Answer (score 0):

You define **If...else** block at class level which is wrong.,so write this in `onPreexecute` method  as

```
  String URL = "";
     protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();

    if (lat!=null && lng!=null)
                { URL = "http://xyz.in/api/stores/around_me.json?app_id=test&lat="
                        + lat + "&lng=" + lng; }
                else
                {
                URL = "http://xyz.in/api/stores/around_me.json?       
                                   app_id=test&lat=12.58&lng=77.38";
                }
    }
```

Comment: `if(lat&&lng!= null)`??

Answer (score 0):

**Check your code is outside the block, write it in a block.**

Check **Errors** after removing following code:

```
Double lat = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider).getLatitude();
Double lng = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider).getLongitude();

**//*************************PROBLEM IN IF ELSE***********************************
if(lat&&lng!= null)
{
   String URL = "http://xyz.in/api/stores/around_me.json?app_id=test&lat=" + lat + "&lng=" + lng; 
} else {
   String URL = "http://xyz.in/api/stores/around_me.json?app_id=test&lat=12.58&lng=77.38";
}
//********************************************************************************

AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");
```

and

Change

```
if(lat!= null && lng!= null)
```

instead of

```
if(lat&&lng!= null)
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem has nothing to do with AsyncTask, the condition has a syntax error and will show it anywhere you put it.

```
if(lat&&lng!= null)
```

lat is not a boolean, and as such can not be evaluated inside an if, I guess what you want is:

```
if (lat!=null && lng!=null)
```

Comment: this code is not even in a code block

Comment: it was answered while I was typing the answer